# Slider Video not working on mobile

Tags: html, video, slider

Hi can you please help me why is that whenever I view my website the 1st slider which is the video.mp4 is not loading, but when I run it on the browser it's working properly. Please Help Thanks in Advance

```
<section id="slider" class="slider-parallax revslider-wrap clearfix">
    <div class="slider-parallax-inner">

        <div class="tp-banner-container rev_slider_wrapper fullscreen-container">
            <div class="tp-banner" >
                <ul>    <!-- SLIDE  -->

                <li data-transition="fade" data-slotamount="1" data-masterspeed="1000" data-thumb="images/slider/rev/main/1.jpg"  data-saveperformance="off"  data-title="" >
                        <!-- MAIN IMAGE images/slider/rev/main/upc1a.jpg -->
                    <img src="images/slider/rev/main/1.jpg"  alt=""  data-bgposition="center center" data-bgfit="cover" data-bgrepeat="no-repeat" data-bgparallax="10" class="rev-slidebg" data-no-retina>

                        <!-- LAYER NR. 1 -->
                        <div class="tp-fade fadeout fullscreenvideo rs-background-video-layer"
                            data-forcerewind="on"
                            data-volume="mute"
                            data-videowidth="100%"
                            data-videoheight="100%"
                            data-videomp4="images/ec.mp4"
                            data-videopreload="preload"
                            data-videoloop="none"
                            data-forceCover="1"
                            data-aspectratio="16:9"
                            data-autoplay="true"
                            data-autoplayonlyfirsttime="false"
                            data-nextslideatend="true"
                            >
                        </div>


                </li>
                <li class="tp-fade fadeout" data-transition="fade" data-slotamount="1" data-masterspeed="1500" data-thumb="images/slider/rev/main/2.jpg" data-delay="300" data-saveperformance="off" data-title="">
                    <!--Main Image-->
                    <img src="images/slider/rev/main/2.jpg"  alt="kenburns6"  data-bgposition="right center" data-kenburns="on" data-duration="3000" data-delay="3000" data-ease="Linear.easeNone" >
                </li>

                <li class="tp-fade fadeout" data-transition="slideup" data-slotamount="1" data-masterspeed="1500" data-thumb="images/slider/rev/main/3.jpg" data-delay="3000" data-saveperformance="off" data-title="">
                    <!--Main Image-->
                    <img src="images/slider/rev/main/3.jpg"  alt="kenburns6"  data-bgposition="right center" data-kenburns="on" data-duration="3000" data-delay="3000" data-ease="Linear.easeNone" >
                </li>

                <li class="tp-fade fadeout" data-transition="fade" data-slotamount="1" data-masterspeed="1500" data-thumb="images/slider/rev/main/4.jpg" data-delay="300" data-saveperformance="off" data-title="">
                    <!--Main Image-->
                    <img src="images/slider/rev/main/4.jpg"  alt="kenburns6"  data-bgposition="right center" data-kenburns="on" data-duration="3000" data-delay="3000" data-ease="Linear.easeNone" >
                </li>

                <li class="tp-fade fadeout" data-transition="slideup" data-slotamount="1" data-masterspeed="1500" data-thumb="images/slider/rev/main/5.jpg" data-delay="5000"  data-saveperformance="off"  data-title="">
                        <!-- MAIN IMAGE  time dalay last edited 11000-->
                        <img src="images/slider/rev/main/5.jpg"  alt="kenburns6"  data-bgposition="left top" data-kenburns="on" data-duration="5000" ata-delay="5000" data-ease="Linear.easeNone" >
                        <!-- LAYERS --> 
                        <a href="#" data-scrollto="#section-about" class="one-page-arrow dark">
                            <i class="icon-angle-down infinite animated fadeInDown"></i>
                        </a>
                </li>
                </ul>

            </div>

        </div>
        <!--<a href="#" data-scrollto="#section-about" data-easing="easeInOutExpo" data-speed="1250" data-offset="65" class="one-page-arrow dark"><i class="icon-angle-down infinite animated fadeInDown"></i></a>-->
    </div>


</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that it is not outplaying, then the autoplay tag is not supported on most mobile devices to avoid users running on large data usage bills.

The poster tag does work, so one common approach is to make sure you have a poster set for the video so that this displays instead on a Mobile.